# Get the text in string variable

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5

I m confused with this from many days and couldn't understand how to resolve it.
I get some data from web server and assigning it to string variable.In assigning it if sometimes no data is available then that string is updated to null(`NULL`) and to `nil`(nil) sometimes to `(null)`.So I m confused how to compare data in that variable.

```
if(stringvariable==NULL) // couldnot understand how to compare here ,with NULL or nil or (null)
{

//  do something
}
```

When will the string variable change its state (to `NULL` or `nil` or `(null)`) ?

Comment: you can use `stringVariable.length==0` || `stringVariable==[NSNull null]`

Comment: if ([stringvariable isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || stringVariable.length==0) {
        
    }

Comment: @IrshadMansuri right irshad sir... :) see my answer its right?? ;)

Comment: @IrshadMansuri now when I print then string variable it is (null).I wrote code like this :if(![appDelegate.userCurrentState isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || ![appDelegate.userCurrentState length]==0){ // Data found } else {// Data not found } But now also it enters if block .Y is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
if(![stringvariable isEqualToString:@""])
{
    // stringvariable is not Empty.
}
else
{
    // stringvariable is Empty.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code..

```
if([stringvariable isEqualToString:@""] || [stringvariable isEqual:nil])
{
    //Data not Found
}
else{
   // Data not nil
}
```

Comment: I tried ur code but when I print the description of stringvariable it is <nil> my code is if(![stringvariable isEqualToString:@""] || ![stringvariable isEqual:nil])
{
    //Data  Found
}
else{
   // Data not found
} Eventhough it enters into if block now..What else can I do ?

Comment: you mean you get <nil> inside the string from web?? its crazy but try with this code may be web return this value in string type.. if(![stringvariable isEqualToString:@"<nil>"]

Comment: @arizah also just post that code where you assign value to this variable `stringvariable`

Comment: See Im taking current state from CLGeocoder and assinging it to a variabe.Sometimes during updating location it is getting (null) and sometimes to nil.So I m unable to compare..

Comment: appDelegate.userCurrentState=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentState]; // where current state is string variable .Now if if(![appDelegate.userCurrentState isEqualToString:@""] || ![appDelegate.userCurrentState isEqual:nil]){Data found} else{//Not found}

Comment: first tell me dear i alloc that string variable in AppDelegate.m file?? like     `userCurrentState = [[NSString alloc]init];
    userCurrentState = @"";' in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of 1AppDelegate.m` class?? just try it out and let me know

Comment: I allocated it and saw .BUt still same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29161/discussion-between-arizah-and-paras-joshi)

Answer (score 0):

You can check like

`if([str length]>0 || ![str isEqualToString:@""]) {`

// String is not empty

`}`